# No provider for @Inject('environment') in Unit Test with Angular & JEST

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jestjs

I have a problem how to test one of our services writing in angular app (version 13).

This is part of the service (AdressService) which I want to test:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AddressService {
  private formDataSource = new BehaviorSubject<ICreateEditAddress>({
    id: null,
    company: null,
    lastName: null,
    firstName: null,
    street: null,
    streetNumber: null,
    zip: null,
    city: null,
    country: null,
    countryOptions: null,
    formFields: null
  });
  public readonly formData = this.formDataSource.asObservable();

  constructor(
    @Inject(LOCALE_ID) private language: string,
    private graphQlService: GraphQLService,
  ) {
  }
  public async getAddressDetailsForm(id?: string | number): Promise<ICreateEditAddress> {
    return this.graphQlService.performStandardQuery<IGetAddressDetailsResponse>({
      query: createEditAddressQuery,
      queryVariables: {
        lang: this.language,
        id: id || null,
      },
      relatedObservable: this.addressGetDetailsObservable,
    }).then(result => {
      if (typeof result?.data?.address === 'object') {
        this.formDataSource.next({
          ...this.filterAddressDetailsResponse(result.data.address)
        });
      }
      return result?.data?.address;
    });
  }
}
```

Inside GraphQLService I have:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class GraphQLService {
  constructor(
    @Inject(LOCALE_ID) protected language: string,
    protected apollo: Apollo,
    protected error: ErrorService,
    private router: Router,
    private browser: BrowserService,
  ) {
  }
}
```

Finally in ErrorService I have:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ErrorService {
  private messageSubject = new Subject<IErrorEvent>();
  public readonly message = this.messageSubject.asObservable();
  private readonly renderer: Renderer2;

  constructor(
    @Inject('environment') public environment: any,
    private browser: BrowserService,
    rendererFactory: RendererFactory2,
  ) {
    this.renderer = rendererFactory.createRenderer(null, null);
  }
}
```

My test case look like:

```
describe('Address service', () => {
  let service: AddressService;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      // imports: [AppModule], { provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/'} - not working, generating error NotSupportedError: This name has already been registered in the registry.
      providers: [AddressService, GraphQLService, Apollo, ErrorService, Router, BrowserService], //
      // providers: [AddressService, GraphQLService, Apollo, ErrorService, Router, BrowserService] -> not working missing declaration for environment which is  @Inject('environment') public environment: any in ErrorService. This is file with configuration, one const which is exported.
      // Error: NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[AddressService -> GraphQLService -> ErrorService -> environment -> environment]: 
      // NullInjectorError: No provider for environment!
    });
    service = TestBed.inject(AddressService);
  });

  it('should be created', () => {
    expect(service).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('should return an empty address', async () => {
    await service.getAddressDetailsForm('1');
    await service.getAddressDetailsForm();
    const form = service.getFormData();
    expect(form.city).toBeNull();
  });
});
```

I try on several way to use @Inject('environment') -> to solve problem. When I adding services like in example above I got error like:

```
NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[AddressService -> GraphQLService -> ErrorService -> environment -> environment]: 
      NullInjectorError: No provider for environment!
```

When I remove all providers but keep only `providers: [AddressServices]` and add `imports: [AppModule]` then I got this error:

```
NotSupportedError: This name has already been registered in the registry.
```

Can you help me to solve that problem?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be importing `AppModule`. In unit tests, you only import/provide the single class/element you are testing, and mock any dependencies it might have.

In this case, you would provide `AddressService`, along with a value for `LOCALE_ID` and a mock of `GraphQLService`. Nothing more.

Comment: Is that any possibility to not use mock data/services but use existing solution?

Comment: Unit testing means mocking dependencies, otherwise you're looking at integration testing. Why do you want to use the "real" services?

Comment: Is a lot of logic to repeat which need other services (let say GraphQLService need 4 other services to work etc). I thing about testing how existing logic working - this is a reason why not to use mock data. I wondering about start using Cypress for that but I'm not sure if Cypress is good for integration test, I used them for E2E test.

Comment: You don't need to mock dependencies of dependencies, that's kind of the whole point. All you need is a mock (or more often a spy) of GraphQLService which has the required methods, and those methods return whichever mock data you choose. You can even store your mock/spy so you don't need to reproduce it in every test suite that has it as a dependency.

Comment: Cypress is for end-to-end indeed, not for integration testing. Your first stop for tests should be unit tests. They're quick to write, and when well devised, robust and easy to maintain. I'd advise you forget about integration/E2E if you haven't got decent unit tests.

Comment: If your real, deep-seated reason for not wanting to use mocks/spies is that you don't know how to build them (the way you talk about them makes that seem to be the case), don't worry: they're extremely easy to build. You can use Jasmine's `createSpy` and `createSpyObj` methods, for example.